# JSP IllegalAccessException can not access public member

Tags: java, jsp, illegalaccessexception

In a JSP-File I have the following call to get to one item of a Map:

```
${map.keySet().iterator().next()}
```

when executing the file I get an IllegalAccessException:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.HashMap$KeySet with modifiers "public"
```

We have currently no idea where this comes from. The curious thing is that the System is developed by four developers and that JSP file works without any problems on three machines (all configured in the same way). There is one machine where we get this Exception.

Comment: I just had a similar problem, and found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-579, which led me to find that my class was of default visibility, and therefore presumably not visible to the other code.